# Can't use my new SSD, it isn't listed

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, sata

**Edit: I got it to work, used the *EaseUS Partition Master* program, it finally detected the disk so I was able to format and assign a letter from there; then, with `DISKPART` I converted it from `GPT to MBR` and succesfully installed W10 on it!**

it's my first time here on superuser and I really need help.

Last day I installed a brand new 240gb SATA SSD (the SATA cable is also new) on my desktop computer (Windows 10 Pro x64) but it doesn't work!

**I can see the SSD in the BIOS, it also appears listed in Device Manager under Disk drives, the driver is up to date.
However, it isn't listed in Disk Management, I can only see my current HDD.**

I tried with the *CMD (as administrator)*...

`DISKPART > LIST DISK` only shows `Disk 0`, witch is the HDD, so I can't select the SSD, can't even assign it a letter.

Can't use `CHKDSK` because the disk has no letter, nothing works.

`MOUNTVOL` shows me the `C: disk` (HDD) and two others that say `*** NO MOUNT POINTS ***`, pretty sure those 2 are refering to the other 2 partitions that my HDD have (for recovery purposes) but I still tried using their GUID/Device ID by using (with both cases) `CHKDSK "\\?\Volume{RANDOM STRING}"` and it founds no problems...

To specify, it's a Kingston SSD A400 240GB, thus I also installed the Kingston SSD Manager aplication they have and not even this shows the disk.

**I also connected the SSD in another computer of mine and it was the same, both BIOS and Device Manager show the disk but nothing else does, not even the Windows Setup program to try and format the SSD from there shows it. EDIT: I also tried changing the Boot from the BIOS from Legacy to UEFI and vice versa.**

I'm desesperated, a entire day wasted triying the same things over and over again... the worst thing is that the pc DOES KNOW, IN A WAY OR ANOTHER, THAT THE SSD DOES EXIST, so it isn't "broken" and can't ask for a replacement o just refund it, please help!

PD: sorry if my english is bad, I tried, I speak spanish.

Comment: Have you tried another SATA cable? Are you sure the SATA cable and port are SATA 3? If all the answers are Yes, then the disk might be defective and you should ask for a replacement.

Comment: Yeah, I tried with 3 different cables, but all of them are SATA 2 tho.

Comment: Also, have you checked that it is compatible with your PC, at a site such as Kingston or Crucial, https://www.crucial.com/products/ssd/ssd-buying-guide .'

Comment: @LeonardoGómez - On the other machine, are you able to mount the volume on the disk and specifically, assign it a drive letter?

Comment: @Romen That’s simply not true. GPT support is entirely independent from UEFI booting. Only on the boot drive are there restrictions.

Comment: @LeonardoGómez Please don’t put the solution in the question. Instead, add an answer.

Comment: @DanielB, Good to know. I just automatically associated the EFI & GPT thing because I personally went through the problem of not being able to boot a GPT disk on a BIOS. Now I always use EFI & GPT and never noticed GPT was visible from MBR booted OS's.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct AHCI drivers installed for your motherboard chipset and any other SATA controller your motherboard has. As well as the chipset driver for your motherboard. Windows Update may automatically find drivers for these things & show you they're OK in device manager, but they still may not be fully featured or up-to-date drivers.

Answer (score -2):

You say you have used SATA 2 cables.

However, the
[Kingston 240GB A400 SATA 3 2.5" Internal SSD SA400S37/240G](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N5IB20Q)
is SATA 3.

Both types are usually compatible and can be mixed.

As you have said:

- As you tried multiple computers, the problem is probably not with the
  computer
- As you have tried more than one cable, the problem is probably not the
  cable
- This leaves the disk.

It's either this one disk that is defective, or you might have found a
rare one that is somehow incompatible with your setup.
Replacing the disk with another of the same model will give the answer,
but perhaps another model is safer.

Comment: SATA is backwards compatible both ways (device and host).

Comment: @DanielB: In theory, but I suspect that there is here one setup in which this does not work.

Comment: @harrymc - SATA backwards compatibility isn’t a theory

Comment: All SATA 1,2,3 cables are identical as far as their electrical performance. Using a "SATA 2" cable on a SATA 3 device could not have any relevance to OP's issue. And as Daniel pointed out, SATA is backwards compatible from both ends, so they will always figure out a successful common protocol level over any working cable.

Comment: Cables are identical, but is the disk so?

Comment: You only mentioned the *cable* was SATA 2, which I tried to explain is irrelevant. OP's question doesn't even indicate that the motherboard is too old to support SATA 3 so it is an assumption that the SATA version is even relevant to the problem at all.

Comment: I fixed the problem, but about this, yeah, the SSD is SATA 3, and so is my Motherboard too, but the cable is SATA 2 and it does work, as stated before, they are backwards compatible, like when you use a normal USB on a 3.0 port or vice versa, it's the same thing. 
As far as I know the only difference by using a SATA 2 cable on a SATA 3 SSD is that you aren't getting the true speed the SSD is capable of, but it stills being waaay faster than an HDD drive, works great, once I get a SATA 3 cable I'll change it tho.

Comment: @LeonardoGómez, there is absolutely no penalty to using a SATA 2 cable on a SATA 3 device. SATA3 is a change to the data/protocol, nothing about the cable changed between SATA 2 and SATA 3. Cable manufacturers put a little metal lock/latch on the SATA 3 cables to convince you they're better & help differentiate them from basic SATA 2 cables.